# Glide: getDecoder() in GifDrawable is missed in version 4.1.1

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

There is a legacy code dependent on getDecoder() of GifDrawable of Glide lib.
After Glide version update from 3.7.0 to 4.1.1 many conflicts appeared.
All of them were fixed except the getting GifDecoder object from GifDrawable object.

So how to construct GifDecoder from GifDrawable (Glide classes)?